# How Can I get a page transition programmatically after getting biometric authentication result true without any button press event in advance?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I am creating an app in flutter implemented local_auth plugin.
I would like this flow below.

```
1.background page(BioAuthScreen) is up
2.simultaneously authenticateWithBiometrics dialog is up.
3.if result is true, get the page transition to HomeScreen(folloing comment // 3),
```

if I pressed the button (the code following comment // 4),
It's work.(up the dialog, if the result is true, the page transition OK).
But I wouldn't like button in background page.
if I put the code following comment // 1 or // 2, the dialog is up, if the result is true,
but background page still there. there's no error.

This is the code.

```
class BioAuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  BioAuthScreen({Key key, this.initFlag = false}) : super(key: key);
  final bool initFlag;

  @override
  _BioAuthScreenState createState() => _BioAuthScreenState();
}

class _BioAuthScreenState extends State<BioAuthScreen>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final LocalAuthentication _localAuthentication = LocalAuthentication();
  bool _isAuthenticated;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    // 1
 /*   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _getAuthenticated();
    }); */
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700));
    // 2
    // await _getAuthenticated();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BioAuthScreen()));
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {}
  }

  Future<List<BiometricType>> _getListOfBiometricTypes() async {
    List<BiometricType> listOfBiometrics;
    try {
      listOfBiometrics = await _localAuthentication.getAvailableBiometrics();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    print(listOfBiometrics);
    return listOfBiometrics;
  }

  Future<void> _getAuthenticated() async {
    var result = false;
    var availableBiometricTypes = await _getListOfBiometricTypes();
    try {
      if (availableBiometricTypes.contains(BiometricType.face) ||
          availableBiometricTypes.contains(BiometricType.fingerprint)) {
        result = await _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(
          localizedReason: '生体認証',
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickyAuth: false,
        );
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    print('result: $result');
    // 3
    if (result) {
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, Constants.homeScreenRoute);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 1,
          heightFactor: 1,
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: CustomColors.midBlue,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                ),
                // Title
                AuthTitleComponent(),
                SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.28),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth:
                      screenWidth > 600 ? screenWidth * 0.6 : screenWidth * 0.7,
                  height: 45,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 3.0,
                    color: CustomColors.lightBlue,
                    // 4
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _getAuthenticated();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'BioMetricAuthLogin',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .headline2
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the reported behavior using the code snippets you've provided. `LocalAuthentication.authenticate` catches PlatformException when biometric auth is called through `didChangeAppLifecycleState`.

This seems to be a bug and I've filed this as an issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77622). I'm using Flutter version 2.0.0 stable and local_auth 1.1.0 for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and report. I had missed the exception. I'm not sure about the details, but it looks like the dialog can't recognize the widget.